# Change width and height of react-dropdown-tree-select component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

Noob web dev here. I'm using a tree based drop
Documentation: [Link](https://dowjones.github.io/react-dropdown-tree-select/#/story/readme)
Live example: [here](https://dowjones.github.io/react-dropdown-tree-select/#/story/with-material-design-styles)

I want to change the height and the width of `"Search/DropDown bar"` in this image [image]

`To be displayed like this:` [image]
But the there's some issues even in-line css doesn't work.

Main component is `DropdownTreeSelect`

See code below:

**DropDown.js**

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import DropdownTreeSelect from "react-dropdown-tree-select";
    import isEqual from "lodash/isEqual";
    import "./DownloadNFT.css";
    
export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: props.data };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (!isEqual(nextProps.data, this.state.data)) {
      this.setState({ data: nextProps.data });
    }
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps) => {
    return !isEqual(nextProps.data, this.state.data);
  };

  render() {
    const { data, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <DropdownTreeSelect
        className="mdl-demo"
        data={this.state.data}
        {...rest}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Many changes were tried to be made in in-line and css but style of the `searchbox/dropdown` is not changing

**DropDown.css**

```
/* fallback, until https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/174 is resolved */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v36/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2)
    format("woff2");
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 54px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* mdl-demo is a custom classname to increases the specificity of our styles. It can be anything. 
 * The idea is that it is easy to extend/override builtin styles with very little effort.
 */

.mdl-demo .dropdown-trigger > span:after {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: rgb(208, 255, 0);
}

.mdl-demo .toggle {
  font: normal normal normal 18px/1 "Material Icons";
  color: #555;
  white-space: pre;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0].placeholder="Search collection";
```

Put it after `render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));`
in (index.js) in the demo example

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the input component's height and width in order to modify the dropdown's initial box.

add the below to your css file

```css
.mdl-demo .tag-item .search{
  width: 300px;
}
```